# Debugging SPI problems on NXP K66

Tags: spi, debugging, nxp

I'm trying the sample provided by K66 SDK from NXP and it doesn't work at all. I attached a scope and monitoring the data that is transfered from the uC to the slave but nothing is there. I have another firmware which is the original software we use it writes random SPI bytes. So I decided to test the NXP SDK SPI Sample to investigate further the problems but there are no outputs at all.

What should I do in that case ? Steps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked with the K64 - it is a powerful beast :)

Checklist:

1. Are you using the right SPI peripheral? SPI0, SPI1, SPI2 etc.
2. Is the clock to the peripheral enabled? (if not you should have got a hard fault)
3. **Is the right pin multiplexing option selected?** The most likely issue in my opinion.
4. Is the driver correct? For example: after you write the SPI data register you have to wait (poll a flag) until the byte is shifted out before writing another byte.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm trying their sample dspi_polling_b2b_transfer_master. There is no clock generated, no data transfer on the scope, nothing is there. For number 3 can you elaborate more ? I'm using SPI0, and the correct pins for it, how do I enable the clock to the peripheral ?

Comment: A question, should be a clock there  that is generated even If I'm not starting transfering any data ?

Comment: here is the code https://pastebin.com/ED2Ct5Uc